# Analyzing a quantum circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, hilbert-space, quantum-computer

[image]

This is an exercise from Nielson Chuang that I am totally stuck at.
First I can't understand why the measurement outcomes are related to the operation on the target bit at all. Second, why is the probability of both measurements outcomes being $0$ is not $1$? All I can see is that $H^2 = I$.

Could anyone please, please help me how to solve this exercise?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried evolving the input state step by step as each circuit element is applied?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is probably telling you that the Hadamards on the left cancel the Hadamards on the right, because "obviously" the controls of a CCNOT are unchanged by the operation. **This intuition is wrong.** Operations affect controls just as much as they affect the target.

[Simulating the circuit in Quirk](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22Amps2%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Amps2%22%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Amps2%22%5D%5D%7D) shows that the textbook's description of what happens looks correct. When the two top qubits end up off, there's a different amount of phasing compared to otherwise:

[image: Circuit simulation]

*(Note: Making the target be an EPR pair is a trick in Quirk to make the state displays of the EPR pair look like the operation's matrix.)*

Solving part (a) of the problem is really just a matter of doing the algebra, multiplying the gates' matrices together, and confirming they have the right behavior.